# Why it has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.?

Tags: cors

I have followed the guide at:

https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/

To create a backend service with serverless, lambda, nodejs.
The endpoint is working correctly if testing with postman.

Below the request headers, how they are set ( I tried to enable everything since to find out the issue) .

```
General:
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 97
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 08 Nov 2019 16:26:15 GMT
status: 400
via: 1.1 xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxx=
x-amz-cf-id: xxxxxx-EFTU2MF4k_TQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: xxxxx-C1
x-amzn-requestid: xxxxxxx-85a7-4d61-bf42-081944a4d307
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-xxxxxxx-37555e2ccf9ab35021c26f98;Sampled=0
x-cache: Error from cloudfront

Request headers
:authority: xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /stg/getConfigUrl
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8
access-control-request-headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
cache-control: no-cache
origin: http://0.0.0.0:8017
pragma: no-cache
referer: http://0.0.0.0:8017/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 ....
```

I think the needed preflight request headers are set. I dont get this error.
What's really meaning that "It does not have HTTP ok status" ?

Trying with Postman (same request) it answer HTTP 200 OK.
But here via browser it seems OPTION request answers 400... why?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your browser before doing the proper XHR request coded in the site you visit, it will ask “Well, I’m in localhost (or web.com)” then it will ask the site the request is pointing to “Hey, what options I have to call you?” after, if the site is well configured it can answer for example “So, I allow requests from collsite.com, but only if you want to GET or POST, then I will allow you to send me all HTTP headers you want” and your browser “Ok, fine! I will check this request and enforce these rules for you!” and next it will throw or not the known “CORS error”.
Technically, It first will do an empty request with verb “OPTIONS” to the site request is pointing.
After it will “catch” specific HTTP headers and check it contents, where this “conversation” is made. For example, “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” that have allowed domains to call or “Access-Control-Allow-Methods” has the allowed methods that these domains can use to call and so on, these and other headers are responsible to allow or not allow the known “CORS”.